# "The X king of Y" or the "X king at Y"?

Tags: word-choice

Example sentence:

> Pike Place brewed coffee is the caffeine king of/at Starbucks.

What's the correct construction? And why?

Comment: I don't really think *the [noun1] king of/at [noun2]* is an idiomatically natural construction in English, so it seems to me it's entirely a matter of opinion which of your two versions is the ***least idiomatically unacceptable*** one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So what's a more idiomatic option in your opinion?

Comment: I'm not sure there is any "natural" way of metaphorically referring to a particular type of coffee as *the caffeine king* (at Starbucks, or in general). There are a few dozen instances of [the alcohol king](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+alcohol+king%22) in Google Books, but they all seem to refer to people who controlled the supply, not the substance itself. If you want to retain the broad thrust of the metaphor, perhaps *When it comes to caffeine at Starbucks, Pike Place **rules*** or similar. But this is writing advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*X is the king of Y* means X rules over Y, and if Y is place, X may or may not physically be there.

*X is the king at Y* means X is a king and is at the place Y, but not necessarily ruling over it.